# Two weird bugs (at least for me) with javascript

Tags: javascript

I`m pretty new to javascript and need some help.

My problems:

1. Everytime I click a menu item and the browser isn`t in full screen, it brings me back to the top of the page..
2. My menu fades in/out tables. I have 5 menu items. When I go through all the menu items 1 by 1, sometimes the page will refresh instead of transitioning the fade-in/out.

Heres the javascript I`m using:

```
$(document).ready(
function() {

    var currentHash = location.hash.split("#");

    if (currentHash.length > 1) {

        var currentHashString = currentHash[1].toString();

        $("#navigation li a").removeClass("selected");

        $("#navigation li a[href*="+currentHashString+"]").addClass("selected");

        var contentCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

        for (i=0;i<contentCollection.length;i++) {
            if (contentCollection[i].id) {
                if (contentCollection[i].id === currentHashString || currentHashString === "") {
                    $(contentCollection[i]).fadeIn(650);
                } else {
                    $(contentCollection[i]).fadeOut(650).css("display", "none");
                    if (location.hash !== "#") {
                        location.hash = "#"+currentHash[1];
                    } // if
                } // else
            } // if
        } // for

    } else {
        var contentCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

        for (i=0;i<contentCollection.length;i++) {
            if (contentCollection[i].id) {
                if (contentCollection[i].id !== "one") {
                    $(contentCollection[i]).fadeOut(650).css("display", "none");
                }
            } // if
        } // for
    } // else

    $("#navigation li a").click(function() {

                                    var myClicked = this.href.split("#");

                                    $("#navigation li a").removeClass("selected");

                                    this.className = "selected";

                                    var contentCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

                                    for (i=0;i<contentCollection.length;i++) {
                                        if (contentCollection[i].id) {
                                            if (contentCollection[i].id === myClicked[1]) {
                                                $(contentCollection[i]).fadeIn(650);    
                                                  } else {
                                                $(contentCollection[i]).fadeOut(650).css("display", "none");
                                                    if (location.hash !== "#") {
                                                        location.hash = "#"+myClicked[1];
                                                    }

                                              } // else

                                        } // if
                                    } // for
                                    return false;
                                } // click func

                            ); // click event
    } // anon func 1

); // ready
```

My HTML is a regular unordered list with tables instead of list items. The fade effect works fine with the tables. I`ll provide more info if needed. Thanks in advance.

The HTML:

```
<!-- Start table area -->
<div id="main-content">
<div id="navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#one" class="selected">Volkswagen</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Audi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">Chrysler</a></li>
    <li><a href="#four">GM</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!-- End Navigation -->
<div id="content-wr">
    <div id="content-slider">
        <ul id="content-slider-inside">
<!-- TABLE 1 -->                
<li id="one">
<table width="759" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr height="3">
            <td height="3" width="3" class="borderhautgauche"></td>
            <td height="3" width="627" class="borderhaut"></td>
            <td height="3" width="3" class="borderhautdroit"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bordergauche"></td>
            <td>
     <table width="752" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="151" class="TopTablehitch">MARQUE</td>
            <td width="187" class="TopTablehitch">MODÈLES</td>
            <td width="178" class="TopTablehitch">SÉRIES</td>
            <td width="236" class="TopTablehitch">ANNÉES</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="texttablehitch" onmouseover="this.className='texttableoverhitch'" onmouseout="this.className='texttablehitch'">
            <td><strong>table1</strong></td>
            <td><strong>table1</strong></td>
            <td>Tous les modèles</td>
            <td>1995-1997</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="texttablehitch" onmouseover="this.className='texttableoverhitch'" onmouseout="this.className='texttablehitch'">
            <td><strong>table1</strong></td>
            <td><strong>table1</strong></td>
            <td>Autres modèles</td>
            <td>1998-2000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="texttablehitch" onmouseover="this.className='texttableoverhitch'" onmouseout="this.className='texttablehitch'">
            <td><strong>table1</strong></td>
            <td><strong>table1</strong></td>
            <td>Tous les modèles</td>
            <td>2010-2012</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="texttablehitch" onmouseover="this.className='texttableoverhitch'" onmouseout="this.className='texttablehitch'">
            <td><strong>table1</strong></td>
            <td><strong>table1</strong></td>
            <td>Tous les modèles</td>
            <td>2000-2011</td>
        </tr>
</table>
</td>
<td class="borderdroit"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="4" class="borderbasgauche"></td>
            <td width="627" class="borderbas"></td>
            <td width="3" class="borderbasdroite"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
</li>
```

There are no closing divs or tags on purpose

Comment: You can use `this` to refer to the element which the event occurred, so you can use `$(this)` to wrap it in a jQuery object, instead of all those `for`s

Comment: Could you show me an example of what you`re mentioning? I`m still learning :/

Comment: Like this: `$("#navigation li a").click(function() { $(this).fadeOut(650); });`

Comment: So just to make sure I understand correctly.. That bit of code is a wrapper much like a div wrapping an html element?

Comment: I`ve been trying to integrate it and I gotta say I`m failing. I`m not sure where to put it and/or what to replace. Maybe I should go back to the books :/ So far your reply was the clearest. Thanks Andre.

Comment: I made a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/tDLNG/1/ - I tried to be clear and comment every important line there, but feel free to ask if you don't understand anything. There you'll find what I said about using `$(this)`, plus some clean ups using dom traversing.

Comment: Thank you again andre. I don`t get any syntax errors in my code when I implement it, but however I do have a problem where all my tables are showing instead of just the current one. If I click on another tab then everything dissapears and the tabs wont load any tables at all.@davorivas: So far your solution works best, but the page still refreshes everytime I click a tab.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle on that? More complete, the merrier. Obviously, the location parts won't work, so you can filter that out

Comment: ( http://jsfiddle.net/lostashell/tDLNG/4/ ) Here it is. When I use your code Andre, Everything works fine now since I changed the version of jquery I`m calling from google. The only problem now is that when I initially load the page all my tables are displayed. Then when I click a tab everything works normally. Its not jumping to the top of the page or refreshing anymore. AWESOME! Just to fix this thing where it displays all the tables and I`m in business. Thanks so much.

Comment: Great! I've fixed this last issue ans made my fiddle an answer, so you can check it as accepted answer if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what was causing the page go to top, but my guess was this line:

```
if (location.hash !== "#") {
    location.hash = "#"+currentHash[1];
```

Anyway, changing the function to a more "jQueryish" style, the problem seems to be fixed:

```
$("#navigation li a").click(function() {
    var el = $(this); 
    el.addClass("selected");

    el.parent().siblings().children("a").removeClass("selected");

    $("#content-slider-inside li").slideUp(650) 
    .eq(el.parent().index()).slideDown(650);

    return false;
});
```

Two modifications I made as suggestion:

- Let the `li`s be hidden by default, adding the rule `#content-slider-inside li { display:none; }`
- Replace fadeIn/fadeOut with slideUp/slideDown respectively, as it makes a more natural switching between content

The last problem you complained (see comments on original question), was that you needed a tab to open by default

To open the desired link on page load, you can trigger a click on the desired element **after** biding the click handler, for example:

```
$("#navigation li a").first().click() // Opens first tab
```

Or, based on your code (warning - this is piece of code is untested):

```
var currentHash = location.hash.split("#");

if(currentHash.length > 1) {
    var currentHashString = currentHash[1].toString();

    $("#navigation li a[href*="+currentHashString+"]").click();
}
else{ 
    $("#navigation li a").first().click();
}
```

**So, here is the final code:**

```
$(function(){
    $("#navigation li a").click(function() {
        var el = $(this); 
        el.addClass("selected");

        el.parent().siblings().children("a").removeClass("selected");

        $("#content-slider-inside li").slideUp(650) 
        .eq(el.parent().index()).slideDown(650);

        return false;
    });

    var currentHash = location.hash.split("#");

    if(currentHash.length > 1) {
        var currentHashString = currentHash[1].toString();

        $("#navigation li a[href*="+currentHashString+"]").click();
    }
    else{ 
        $("#navigation li a").first().click();
    }
});
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tDLNG/7/

Comment: I don`t know how to thank you Andre. You saved me a huge headache. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure your browser doesn't try to follow the link to "#".

```
$("#navigation li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Page jumping to the top is caused because your old data vanishes before the new data appears.  Set a static height on the container during transition to prevent this.

Comment: Im still pretty new at javascript. Where exactly do I stick that bit of code in my javascript? Thanks for the quick replies.

Comment: Sorry for the double post but I can`t make the container div a fixed height because it needs to expand automatically with the data entered. Unless there is some other way to give it a fixed height on the container div and still have it expand with more table rows for example...

Comment: 1. Replace your current binding to click().
2. Set the div to a fixed height until the new data has been loaded, then set it back to height:auto.

Comment: I`m real sorry, I feel like a moron... I`m not that javascript savvy. What I really need is a visual example of your replies. If you could show me an example of where to put the code    $("#navigation li a").click(function(e) {     e.preventDefault(); Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @Dave: OP is already returning false from click event handler, which in jQuery is equivalent to both stop propagation and prevent default. He doesn't need to explicitly call `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score -1):

since you provided all that JS can you provide some HTML as well?

**EDIT**

TRY replacing your current function with these lines:

```
$("#navigation li a").click(function() {
 // LOCK SCROLL POSITION
  var scrollPosition = [
    self.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft,
    self.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop  || document.body.scrollTop
  ];
  var html = jQuery('html'); // it would make more sense to apply this to body, but IE7 won't have that
  html.data('scroll-position', scrollPosition);
  html.data('previous-overflow', html.css('overflow'));
  html.css('overflow', 'hidden');
  window.scrollTo(scrollPosition[0], scrollPosition[1]);


var myClicked = this.href.split("#");

$("#navigation li a").removeClass("selected");

this.className = "selected";

var contentCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (i=0;i<contentCollection.length;i++) {
    if (contentCollection[i].id) {
        if (contentCollection[i].id === myClicked[1]) {
            $(contentCollection[i]).fadeIn(650);    
              } else {
            $(contentCollection[i]).fadeOut(650).css("display", "none");
                if (location.hash !== "#") {
                    location.hash = "#"+myClicked[1];
                }

          } // else

    } // if
} // for

/* RESTORE SCROLL */

var html = jQuery('html');
var scrollPosition = html.data('scroll-position');
html.css('overflow', html.data('previous-overflow'));
window.scrollTo(scrollPosition[0], scrollPosition[1])



return false;
} // click func

); // click event
```

Comment: I just edited my original post and added the html that goes with it.